# PID Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, pid

I want to implement a PD controller in Arduino using the PID library. Should I put Ki=0 and the rest of the constants as desired?

```cpp
/*
BALL BALANCING USING A PID CONTROL with 6" resistive Touchscreen
*/
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///Libraries///
#include <PID_v1.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <TouchScreen.h>
#include <Servo.h>

//______________________________________________________________
// Definitions TOUCH PINS
#define YP A1 //brown
#define XM A2 //black
#define YM 7  //yellow
#define XP 6  //red

//______________________________________________________________
// For better pressure precision, we need to know the resistance
// between XP and XM Use any multimeter to read it
// For the 6" its 273 ohms across the X plate
#define Rx 273 //  Resistance in Ohm of Touchscreen measured in X-Direction
TouchScreen ts = TouchScreen(XP, YP, XM, YM, Rx); 

// Coordinates Touchscreen 
TSPoint p; 
double xmin = 146.0;  //154
double xmax = 854.0;   //851
double xLength = 160.0; //Width of Touchscreen in mm at 6.0" 158

double ymin = 63.0;    //63.0  
double ymax = 953.0;    //950.0
double yLength = 96.0; //Length of Touchscreen in mm at 6.0" 94

double convertX = xLength / (xmax - xmin);   // converts raw x values to mm. found through manual calibration  0.2295   0.225988
double convertY = yLength / (ymax - ymin);   // converts raw y values to mm. found through manual calibration  0.1082   0.107865

//______________________________________________________________
//Center-Position
double x0=74.35; double y0=42.71; //center  Correct: 0.5//-7     double x0=74.35; double y0=42.71
//______________________________________________________________

int state = 0;

// servos variables
Servo servoX; //X axis
Servo servoY; //Y axis

/////TIME SAMPLE
int Ts = 45;  //Delay between taking samples/measurements

unsigned long Stable=0;
unsigned int noTouchCount = 0; //variable for noTouch
//______________________________________________________________

double Kpx = 0.08;  //Kpx = 0.08; //Proportional (P) Get the ball to set point                                         
double Kix = 0.02;  //Kix = 0.02 0.022 //Integral (I)                                            
double Kdx = 0.035;  //Kdx = 0.035; //Derivative (D)  Stop the ball at set point 

double Kpy =0.08;  //Kpy = 0.08                                                     
double Kiy =0.02; //Kiy = 0.02 0.022;                                                      
double Kdy =0.035;  //Kdy = 0.035;



//______________________________________________________________
//INIT PID
double SetpointX, InputX, OutputX; //for X
double SetpointY, InputY, OutputY; //for Y
PID myPIDX(&InputX, &OutputX, &SetpointX, Kpx, Kix, Kdx, REVERSE);
PID myPIDY(&InputY, &OutputY, &SetpointY, Kpy, Kiy, Kdy, REVERSE);
//______________________________________________________________

void setup(){ 
servoX.attach(9);
servoY.attach(10);

  OutputX=92;
  OutputY=100;
  servoX.write(OutputX); // Make Plate flat in X-Direction
  servoY.write(OutputY); // Make Plate flat in Y-Direction

   
  //INIT OF TOUSCHSCREEN
   p = ts.getPoint();
   
 
  //INIT SETPOINT, Center of Plate
  SetpointX = 0.0;
  SetpointY = 0.0;
         
  //Setup PID Controller
  myPIDX.SetMode(AUTOMATIC); 
  myPIDX.SetOutputLimits(77, 107); // 83 107
  myPIDY.SetMode(AUTOMATIC); 
  myPIDY.SetOutputLimits(85, 115); // -- 81 105
  
  // TIME SAMPLE
  myPIDX.SetSampleTime(Ts); 
  myPIDY.SetSampleTime(Ts);  
  delay(100);

  state=0;
  setDesiredPosition();

} // end of setup


void loop()
{
  while(Stable < 15)    //REGULATION LOOP 
  {    
   p = ts.getPoint();   //measure pressure on plate
   if (p.x > 0 ) //ball is on plate
   {
      servoX.attach(9); servoY.attach(10); //connect servos
      setDesiredPosition();  
      noTouchCount = 0;  
      p = ts.getPoint(); // measure actual position 
      InputX = (p.x - xmin) * convertX;  // read and convert X coordinate
      InputY = (p.y - ymin) * convertY;  // read and convert Y coordinate  
      if((InputX == SetpointX && InputY == SetpointY )) 
      
          { Stable = Stable + 1;}
        
       myPIDX.Compute();  // action control X compute
       myPIDY.Compute();  // action control  Y compute   
  }
   else //if there is no ball on plate
  {
    noTouchCount++; //increment no touch count
    if(noTouchCount == 150) 
    {
     noTouchCount++;   
     OutputX=92; OutputY=100;  //make plate flat
     servoX.write(OutputX); servoY.write(OutputY);
    }
    if(noTouchCount == 300) //if there is no ball on plate longer, detach servos
    { servoX.detach(); servoY.detach(); }
  }
  servoX.write(OutputX); servoY.write(OutputY);  //control 
      
  } // END OF REGULATION LOOP

servoX.detach(); servoY.detach(); //detach servos

///STABILITY////
 while(Stable==15)    //if is stable 
 { //still measure actual postiion
    setDesiredPosition(); 
    p = ts.getPoint();
    InputX = (p.x - xmin) * convertX;  // read and convert X coordinate
    InputY = (p.y - ymin) * convertY; // read and convert Y coordinate
    if(InputX < SetpointX || InputX > SetpointX || InputY > SetpointY || InputY < SetpointY  ) //if ball isnt close to setpoint
    {
      servoX.attach(9); //again attach servos
      servoY.attach(10);
      Stable=0; //change STABLE state
    }
    
  }//end of STABLE LOOP
}//loop end

//______________________________________________________________
//#### DESIRED POSITION ####
void setDesiredPosition(){
 switch(state){

// Start-Sequence               
     case 0:  SetpointX = x0;
              SetpointY = y0;
              p = ts.getPoint();
              if (p.x > 0)
              { 
                state = 1; 
              } // if ball is on plate
              else if (p.x <= 0)
              { 
                state = 0; 
                setDesiredPosition();  
               } // if no ball is on plate              
              break;

// Center-Position                
      case 1:  SetpointX = x0; 
               SetpointY = y0;
               state = 1;
               break;

    default : state = 0; break;
         
 }  //end of switch state
}   //end of setDesiredPosition()

//______________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Maybe? Without any context it's impossible to help.

Comment: I'm doing a project on ball balancing using a PID controller in arduino UNO
My plant is of type-2 and fifth order system.

Comment: you can check the code above

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the PID library with `Ki=0;` to get a PD controller.